# How to convert a Hive (ORC format) table to a TFRecord file and store in HDFS?

Tags: python, hive, hdfs, hortonworks-data-platform, tensorflow-datasets

I’m working on deploying a TensorFlow model to production and would like to update my data pipeline to consume TFRecord file(s) with tf.data.

How can I convert a Hive table stored in ORC format (Hortonworks distribution) into a TFRecord file format that is stored in HDFS?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please reformulate your post such that you are asking a clear and specific question. As it is, it seems that you've fallen into the [XY pitfall](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @chb I updated my question to be more clear and specific.